# Is rain like bullets at supersonic speed?

Tags: design

https://web.archive.org/web/20230719190548/https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/100037/is-rain-like-bullets-at-supersonic-speed

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Nv6ZqpM-5dY

The video (a marketing video) makes this claim.

I wonder if it is plausible.

Let's do some math.

1 gram at 1000 m/s. 1 kilojoule.

So it seems like at supersonic speeds a raindrop is like a bullet.

Comment: I do not think that raindrops have 1 cc volume

Comment: You can just Google "Flying supersonic in rain": https://www.specialised-imaging.com/about-us/news/what-happens-when-it-rains-on-supersonic-aircraft and https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/how-do-aircraft-windshields-not-crack-when-flying-at-supersonic-speeds-through-p and http://www.aem.umn.edu/people/faculty/joseph/archive/docs0/96_2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Let's try [.034 g](https://www.google.com/search?q=mass%20of%20a%20raindrop&rlz=1C1ONGR_enCA996CA996&oq=mass&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j35i39j0i67i650l2j69i61l3.1319j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), [343 m/s](https://www.google.com/search?q=speed%20of%20osund&rlz=1C1ONGR_enCA996CA996&oq=speed%20of%20osund&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i10i433i512j0i10i512l8.2700j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8): I get [2 joules](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/physics/kinetic.php).

.22 long rifle [KE = ~ 135 J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.22_Long_Rifle).

So no, it isn't even close.  The key here is to verify the assumptions in your calculations.

Comment: @FFff, look at the links. 1000 joules is wrong.